# Hiding warning messaging autoUpdate primefaces JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces, warnings

I have in my logger these messages type INFO, I don't want to hide all INFO logs, only I want to remove (avoid) messages of primefaces.

```
14:11:08,325 INFO  [org.primefaces.component.outputpanel.OutputPanelRenderer] 
    (default task-2) autoUpdate attribute is deprecated and will be removed in a future 
    version, use p:autoUpdate component instead.


14:11:08,325 INFO  [org.primefaces.component.growl.GrowlRenderer] 
    (default task-2) autoUpdate attribute is deprecated and will be removed in a future 
    version, use p:autoUpdate component instead.

14:11:08,325 INFO  [org.primefaces.component.messages.MessagesRenderer] 
    (default task-2) autoUpdate attribute is deprecated and will be removed in a future
    version, use p:autoUpdate component instead.
```

Is it possible?
Yes? How to do it?

Comment: Hi, please always post version info with questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible?

Yes

> Yes?

Yes (if the answer to the former question would have been no, the answer to this one would also have been no ;-) )

> How to do it?

Three options:

- Set the logging of just the PrimeFaces components to 'WARNING'
- Download the source and find this log line and change it to e.g. DEBUG, recompile and use that (or add an additional check around it that only shows it in development mode)
- Check if you actually use the `autoUpdate` attribute and 'fix' it so you use the new `<p:autoUpdate .. />` element instead